# How to auto play video on Chrome after version 66

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video

I'm going to play video on Chrome. However, the latest policy of chrome has changed. So I cannot play the video without user interaction. I'm testing on Chrome Canary version 66 currently. 
It seems that youtube, netflix, twitch and youku are able to play video automatically. So I guess they are not affected by this policy. I'm still investigating their solutions. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

The following are investigated procedure.

1. Open tab with web page, autoplay failure. Press browser refresh / open console exec window.location.reload(). Autoplay success. Turn off tab. Open new tab with web page, autoplay failure.
2. Open tab with web page, video muted, autoplay success. Js trigger page refresh. video unmute, autoplay failure.

Test environment:

- mp4 file
- video information: width 854 / height 480, 52sec
- video dom size: width 427px / height 240px

Comment: You have to change chrome settings by typing command  chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy and then select No user gesture is required.

Comment: http://backtothevitals.com/ seems to have figured it out. Looks like there's some javascript in their wp-custom-header.min.js that is managing the video autoplay. I haven't dug in to find the solution yet.

Comment: I'm also taking a look at https://www.classyllama.com which is using http://jplayer.org/ and it's autoplay feature is working...

Comment: Hi @kevnk, thx for your reply. I looked backtothevitals and classyllama. They could autoplay video because their video was muted which was chrome auto policy requirement.

Comment: Hi @RajeevVarshney, thx for your reply. Your suggestion is good for my testing after I turn off "no user gesture is required". However, I want my video can be played in every viewer. I cannot told them to turn off their setting. Thus, I will keep my investigate.